# How to change the text color inside the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and I'm trying to figure out how to change the text color when hovered.
I've tried what i have found online but it still won't work when hovered the text is still black
Below is my HTML code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 20%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 25px 40px;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav li:hover {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: rgb(6, 168, 106);
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
<title>Deux Citronella Trading</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <h4>LOGO</h4>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I'm also wondering why i can't cover the whole navigation when being hovered to, as you can see on the screenshot below
[image]

is there also a way for me to cover or change the whole background color of the navigation bar when being hovered to?

Comment: add nav li:hover a{color:#fff}. Because first you declare a color black for the links

Comment: See Sfili_81's comment.
You can add :hover to the containing element as well, then the contained elements, unless declared further down the tree, will change style.

If you want to change all li's text colors, for example, when hovering over nav, you need to declare ``nav:hover li a {color:orange;}``, for example.

Comment: a simple `.nav-links li:hover { background-color: rgb(6, 168, 106); } ` will do this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the style for the children like this

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 20%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 25px 40px;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav li:hover {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: rgb(6, 168, 106);
}

nav li:hover a{color:#fff}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <title>Deux Citronella Trading</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <h4>LOGO</h4>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you don't want to add a new line to css and ok with your code you could use `color:inherit` for `<a>` this will inherit the color from its parent element `li`

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 20%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 25px 40px;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav li:hover {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: rgb(6, 168, 106);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <title>Deux Citronella Trading</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <h4>LOGO</h4>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to target your anchor separately and have two hover declarations. Add the following (in addition to the CSS for your list item):

```
nav li:hover a {
  color:#fff;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 20%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 25px 40px;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(6, 168, 106);
}

nav li:hover a {
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <title>Deux Citronella Trading</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <h4>LOGO</h4>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
nav li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing to wrong selector. Your is selector is `a`. So you should put your CSS like this.

```
nav li:hover nav { /*If you want to change background of whole navbar when hovering one item*/
    background-color: rgb(6, 168, 106);
}


nav li a:hover { /*This will change items text color when you hover*/
    color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below css for changing the color for hovering:

```
nav li:hover a {
    color: white
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(6, 168, 106);
}
```